# create and iterate over dictionary of dictonaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have 3 lists and i want to create dictionary of dictionaries. Then i want to iterate over the keys and the values.

```
a = ['ibm','dell']
```

I create dictionary using the list

```
moo = dict.fromkeys([ x for x in a])
```

then I add values to the dict.

```
b = ['strength', 'weakness']

for k in moo.keys():
    moo[k] = b
```

now I want to create the list items of b as keys and add the c list as values:

```
c = ['url1.com', 'url2.com']
```

so the final output should be like:

```
moo = {'ibm': {'strength': ['url1', 'url2'], 'weakeness': ['url3', 'url4']}, ......}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = ['ibm','dell']
b = ['strength', 'weakness']
c = ['url1.com', 'url2.com']

moo = {}
for k in a:
    moo[k] = dict((kk, c) for kk in b)

print(moo)
{'dell': {'strength': ['url1.com', 'url2.com'],
  'weakness': ['url1.com', 'url2.com']},
 'ibm': {'strength': ['url1.com', 'url2.com'],
  'weakness': ['url1.com', 'url2.com']}}
```

Comment: Thanks, Can you also help me with something quick. In place of c if i want to combine a & b and add them as dictionary of dictionaries how would i do that